How to get historical exchange rate data from the European Central Bank API?
I have trouble getting historical exchange rate data from the ECB API: https://data.ecb.europa.eu/help/api/overview
I am an absolute novice and so far I was only able to get the current exchange rates through https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml
The end result I would like to achieve is a something like this (exchange rates for EURO):



Date
USD
GBP




2024-08-29
1.09
0.92


2024-08-28
1.12
0.89



... back to 2000-January-1 (or if the info does not exist this far back: as far back as it exists)
I am working in Power Query M (PowerBI).
The query I use right now is the following, however this does not output what I actually need. It Outputs this:



Currency_name
Rate
Date




USD
1.11
2024-08-27


GBP
0.84
2024-08-27



let

    url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml",
    

    Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents(url)),
    

    ExpandedSender = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Sender", {"name"}, {"Sender.name"}),
    ExpandedEurofxref = Table.ExpandTableColumn(ExpandedSender, "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref", {"Cube"}, {"Eurofxref.Cube"}),
    ExpandedCube = Table.ExpandTableColumn(ExpandedEurofxref, "Eurofxref.Cube", {"Cube"}, {"Cube.Cube"}),
    ExpandedCubeCube = Table.ExpandTableColumn(ExpandedCube, "Cube.Cube", {"Cube", "Attribute:time"}, {"Cube.Cube.Cube", "Date"}),
    ExpandedRate = Table.ExpandTableColumn(ExpandedCubeCube, "Cube.Cube.Cube", {"Attribute:currency", "Attribute:rate"}, {"Currency", "Rate"}),
    

    FilteredCurrencies = Table.SelectRows(ExpandedRate, each [Currency] = "USD" or [Currency] = "GBP"),
    

    ReplacedComma = Table.TransformColumns(FilteredCurrencies, {{"Rate", each Text.Replace(Text.From(_), ".", ","), type text}}),
    

    USDDate = Table.SelectRows(ReplacedComma, each [Currency] = "USD"){0}[Date],
    

    EURRow = Table.FromRecords({
        [Currency = "EUR", Rate = "1", Date = USDDate]
    }),
    

    CombinedTable = Table.Combine({ReplacedComma, EURRow}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(CombinedTable,{"subject", "Sender.name"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Currency", "Currency_name"}})
    
in
    #"Renamed Columns"

Would highly appreciate some help. Thank you very much <3
-L

I had to look for a source that contains everything, see if this is what you need.
If the answer helped, please mark it at this answer is useful. Euro is always 1, if you need a EUR column, put a new column with value 1. your source in the other code is daily report.
   let

    url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-sdmx.xml",
    Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents(url)),
    Table = Source{1}[Table],
    Table1 = Table{0}[Table],
    Table2 = Table1{1}[Table],
    #"Obs Expandido" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Table2, "Obs", {"Attribute:TIME_PERIOD", "Attribute:OBS_VALUE"}, {"Obs.Attribute:TIME_PERIOD", "Obs.Attribute:OBS_VALUE"}),
    #"Linhas Filtradas" = Table.SelectRows(#"Obs Expandido", each ([#"Attribute:CURRENCY"] = "GBP" or [#"Attribute:CURRENCY"] = "USD")),
    #"Colunas Reordenadas" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Linhas Filtradas",{"Obs.Attribute:TIME_PERIOD", "Obs.Attribute:OBS_VALUE", "Attribute:CURRENCY", "Attribute:FREQ", "Attribute:CURRENCY_DENOM", "Attribute:EXR_TYPE", "Attribute:EXR_SUFFIX", "Attribute:TIME_FORMAT", "Attribute:COLLECTION"}),
    #"Colunas Removidas" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Colunas Reordenadas",{"Attribute:FREQ", "Attribute:CURRENCY_DENOM", "Attribute:EXR_TYPE", "Attribute:EXR_SUFFIX", "Attribute:TIME_FORMAT", "Attribute:COLLECTION"}),
    #"Coluna em pivô" = Table.Pivot(#"Colunas Removidas", List.Distinct(#"Colunas Removidas"[#"Attribute:CURRENCY"]), "Attribute:CURRENCY", "Obs.Attribute:OBS_VALUE"),
    #"Linhas Classificadas" = Table.Sort(#"Coluna em pivô",{{"Obs.Attribute:TIME_PERIOD", Order.Descending}})
in
    #"Linhas Classificadas"

or
let

    url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.xml",
    Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents(url)),
    #"Sender Expandido" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Sender", {"name"}, {"Sender.name"}),
    #"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref Expandido" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Sender Expandido", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref", {"Cube"}, {"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube"}),
    #"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube Expandido" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref Expandido", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube", {"Cube"}, {"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube.Cube"}),
    #"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube.Cube Expandido" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube Expandido", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube.Cube", {"Cube", "Attribute:time"}, {"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube.Cube.Cube", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube.Cube.Attribute:time"}),
    #"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube.Cube.Cube Expandido" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube.Cube Expandido", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube.Cube.Cube", {"Attribute:currency", "Attribute:rate"}, {"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube.Cube.Cube.Attribute:curr", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube.Cube.Cube.Attribute:rate"}),
    #"Colunas Removidas" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube.Cube.Cube Expandido",{"subject", "Sender.name"}),
    #"Colunas Renomeadas" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Colunas Removidas",{{"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube.Cube.Cube.Attribute:curr", "Currency"}, {"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube.Cube.Cube.Attribute:rate", "Rate"}, {"http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref.Cube.Cube.Attribute:time", "Time"}}),
    #"Colunas Reordenadas" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Colunas Renomeadas",{"Time", "Currency", "Rate"}),
    #"Linhas Filtradas" = Table.SelectRows(#"Colunas Reordenadas", each ([Currency] = "GBP" or [Currency] = "USD")),
    #"Coluna em pivô" = Table.Pivot(#"Linhas Filtradas", List.Distinct(#"Linhas Filtradas"[Currency]), "Currency", "Rate"),
    #"Linhas Classificadas" = Table.Sort(#"Coluna em pivô",{{"Time", Order.Descending}}),
    #"Valor Substituído" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Linhas Classificadas",".",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"USD"}),
    #"Valor Substituído1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Valor Substituído",".",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"GBP"})
in
    #"Valor Substituído1"


This is perfect, thank you so very much for your help.
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.xml
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-sdmx.xml
I couldn't even find these URLs myself when trying. Very insightful. Thanks again.

Paste this last routine at the end of the code...
...
        #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Currency", "Currency_name"}}),
        #"Coluna em pivô" = Table.Pivot(#"Renamed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Renamed Columns"[Currency_name]), "Currency_name", "Rate", List.Max)
    in
        #"Coluna em pivô"


Thank you! This changed the columns and rows to be in the format I outlined in my original post, however I am still missing the historical data, I am only getting one entry for today. Is that something where you would have an idea as well maybe?

Please try the code below:
// API page: https://data.ecb.europa.eu/help/api/data
let    
    Query = Web.Contents("https://data-api.ecb.europa.eu/service/data/EXR/",
        [
            RelativePath=
                "D." //the frequency at which they are measured (e.g. daily – code D)
                &"USD." //the currency being measured (e.g. US dollar – code USD, all currencies - keep only .);
                &"EUR." //the currency against which the above currency is being measured (e.g. euro – code 
                &"SP00." //the type of exchange rates (e.g. foreign exchange reference rates – code SP00
                &"A" //the Time series variation (e.g. average or standardised measure for a given frequency – code 
            ,
            Query=
            [
                startPeriod="2014-01-01",
                endPeriod=DateTime.ToText(DateTime.LocalNow(), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
                format="csvdata"
            ]
        ]
    ),
    Source = Csv.Document(Query,[Delimiter=",", Columns=32, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"KEY", type text}, {"FREQ", type text}, {"CURRENCY", type text}, {"CURRENCY_DENOM", type text}, {"EXR_TYPE", type text}, {"EXR_SUFFIX", type text}, {"TIME_PERIOD", type date}, {"OBS_VALUE", type text}, {"OBS_STATUS", type text}, {"OBS_CONF", type text}, {"OBS_PRE_BREAK", type text}, {"OBS_COM", type text}, {"TIME_FORMAT", type duration}, {"BREAKS", type text}, {"COLLECTION", type text}, {"COMPILING_ORG", type text}, {"DISS_ORG", type text}, {"DOM_SER_IDS", type text}, {"PUBL_ECB", type text}, {"PUBL_MU", type text}, {"PUBL_PUBLIC", type text}, {"UNIT_INDEX_BASE", type text}, {"COMPILATION", type text}, {"COVERAGE", type text}, {"DECIMALS", Int64.Type}, {"NAT_TITLE", type text}, {"SOURCE_AGENCY", type text}, {"SOURCE_PUB", type text}, {"TITLE", type text}, {"TITLE_COMPL", type text}, {"UNIT", type text}, {"UNIT_MULT", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

If you need to change something read the API documentation  https://data.ecb.europa.eu/help/api/data
